# Matlab button's Callback function that know which figure it is in

Tags: matlab, button, callback

I would like to know how to be able to retreive the number of the figure in the callback function of the clicked button.

I have many figures, each with a button inside:

[image]

The figures are generated inside of a loop:

```
for i=1:n
    h(i) = figure();
    % Generation of the plot
    ...
    % Creation of the button
    uicontrol('Parent',gcf,'Position',[0, 0, 10, 50],'String',{  'Edit' },...
              'Callback', '...' );
end
```

I would like to create a button with a callback function that allows to enter a new function, with input argmuents related to the figure the button have been clicked.

Typically, if the button of figure 15 is pressed, I would like the callback of the function to call:

```
mycalledfunction(15)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't you just use [`gcf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html)?

Comment: What about setting `Tag` in the button properties?

Comment: Thank you Luis Mendo, that is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't actually know that gcf returned a number!

Comment: @AlexandreWillame I'll post it as an answer then so you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gcf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html) to get a handle to the current figure.